# activerecord : database default value not taking effect

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the form to fill the student details which will add the value to the table called 'student'.

In that table I have the column called 'ctime' which has the database default value.

**column structure**

*ctime  | timestamp without time zone | not null default now()*

So while adding a new student I didn't give value to ctime column in the form, but it resulted with the error "PG::Error: ERROR:  null value in column "ctime" violates not-null constraint".

My question is, why it is resulting with error even it has default value in database?.

Kindly help me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have defined a column with some static default value  in the table schema, the corresponding property in the AR instance will automatically have such a value after the instance is created. Check if you are assigning the default value appropriately.

You can set a default option for the column in the migration OR You can use a callback, `before_save`

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :default_values
  def default_values
    self.status ||= 'value'
  end
end
```

Or you could even use the `after_initialize` method to set the default values.